# What delimiter characters are supported with sed 4.4

Tags: sed

I was expecting these two sed commands to be equivalent, but `mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt` is only removed in the second case, why?

I'm using sed 4.4 with Debian stretch if that matters

```
(stretch-arm64)ubuntu@ip-10-1-2-224:~$ sudo sed '#^mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt$#d' test-certificates.conf
mozilla/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
mozilla/XRamp_Global_CA_Root.crt
mozilla/certSIGN_ROOT_CA.crt
mozilla/ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.crt
mozilla/emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_C3.crt
mozilla/emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_G3.crt
mozilla/emSign_Root_CA_-_C1.crt
mozilla/emSign_Root_CA_-_G1.crt
mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt

(stretch-arm64)ubuntu@ip-10-1-2-224:~$ sudo sed '/^mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt$/d' test-certificates.conf
mozilla/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
mozilla/XRamp_Global_CA_Root.crt
mozilla/certSIGN_ROOT_CA.crt
mozilla/ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.crt
mozilla/emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_C3.crt
mozilla/emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_G3.crt
mozilla/emSign_Root_CA_-_C1.crt
mozilla/emSign_Root_CA_-_G1.crt
```

Comment: Reading the manual, it seems avoiding `#` (unless you want to write a comment) is a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the following is valid in any `sed`, not just GNU `sed`.

The `#` character introduces a comment.  It can be considered a "comment command" that makes `sed` ignore the rest of that instruction.  This is why your command does not *do* anything, without producing errors.

To use `#` as an alternative delimiter to the regular expression used as an address, use `\#...#`.  This is not special for `#` but for any character you want to use as an alternative delimiter.

The characters that *can't* be used as delimiters in this context are backslash and newline. Using multi-byte characters is also not generally supported.

No special escaping should be done to use `#` as the delimiter in the `s` command (`s#...#...#`).

---

The only instance where `#` acts as more than a mere comment character is if the two first characters in a `sed` editing script are `#n`.  This is equivalent to running `sed` with its `-n` option (which turns off the default output of the editing buffer at the end of each cycle).

```bash
$ echo hello | sed -e 'y/h/y/'
yello
$ echo hello | sed -e '#n' -e 'y/h/y/'
$ echo hello | sed -e '#n' -e 'y/h/y/' -e p
yello
```

Comment: Note that GNU `sed` doesn't support multibyte characters as delimiter